# Vuefire dynamic path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

How to set the path for vuefire like below

```
export default {
  firebase: {
    classlist: db.ref('chapter/1'),  // here 1  need to be taken from data
    // like this db.ref('chapter/' + this.chapterid),
  },
  data:{
     chapterid:'' 
  },
  mounted:{
  // getchapterid here  
  this.chapterid=getChapterId()

  }
}
```

It does not work it returns error undefined chapterid , is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use function syntax for firebase, otherwise `this` is not bound to vue instance.

```
firebase() {
  return {
   classlist: db.ref('chapter/' + this.chapterid)
  }
},
```

---

Source : https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/90